# I am writing a code calculator app using android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am write an code calculator program which has two button adv and basic . So when user click on adv. all adv. function btn will be display like log, inv and squareroot . and when the user clicks on basic then basic symbols like +,-,*,/, and nos will be displayed . So I am thinking of using fragments to view the buttons according to the adv or basic button is clicked. Is there any other thing that I can use instead of fragment that can be suggested . please enligthen me about this topic.[image]

Comment: maybe dynamically adding and removing the views from your layout? for example if you have LinearLayout ll, Button btn do this: ll.add(btn) or ll.remove(btn)

Comment: In simple way you can do like this..create two layouts, one for adv and other for basic button. then just change visibility of layouts on button click.

Comment: @Ketan Ahir +1 , you expressed it better and more related to the question starter's question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

You create 2 layouts and dynamically set them on your buttons' onClickListener or.

You define 2 fragments and dynamically add and remove them whenever you click your modes. Personally, I prefer fragments.